# CALayer won't redraw

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode6, core-animation, calayer

I have an NSBox containing a hierarchy of layer-backed views. If i add a subview to the NSBox and add gaussian-blur to the background filters (which works perfectly) and then remove the view again, the layer seem to stick around and keeping the drawing, or the hierarchy's layer may keep the information. I can't figure out how to reset/redraw/what-ever-it-takes to remove this "burned in" image.

I'm very new to Core-Animation and Quartz so it might very well be straight forward but I can't get my head around it.

**Edit:** The problem only exists when a CALayer above a SourceList was blurred and transparency is on (OS X Yosemite). If transparency is off there's no issue.

(Sorry for the red lines)
[image]

[image]

Comment: There isn't a huge amount of info here but as standard if you want a layer to redraw itself and it's sublayers you call `[layer setNeedsLayout];` much like `NSView`s `setNeedsDisplay`

Comment: I did try that without luck.